# If radio button is check display a textbox Jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Hey Ya'll I have got a question with my radio buttons I have these 3 buttons

```
No <input type="radio" name="answer" checked="checked" value="no"/> 
Yes<input type="radio" name="answer" value="yes"/> 
Other <input type="radio" name="answer" value="other"/>
```

I also have this text box

```
<input style="display:none;" type="text" name="otherAnswer" id="otherAnswer"/>
```

if the user selects the radio button with the value of "other" then display the textbox, if its anything else dont display the textbox.

I am fairly new to Jquery and I have looked up syntax for this but its all greek to me. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){

   if($(this).val()=="other")
   {
      $("#otherAnswer").show();
   }
   else
   {
       $("#otherAnswer").hide(); 
   }

});
```

Here is the working example : http://jsfiddle.net/Wc2GS/8/

Answer (score 3):

While the answers above are sufficient if you're keen on using jquery/ javascript, this can be very easily achieved using just CSS. Try it on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tanushreemarwah/pen/dyXrxGg).

```css
#otherAnswer {
    display: none;
}
#other:checked ~ #otherAnswer {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
No<input type="radio" id="no" name="answer" checked="checked" value="no"/>

Yes<input type="radio" id="yes" name="answer" value="yes"/>


Other<input type="radio" id="other" name="answer" value="other"/> 
        

<input type="text" id="otherAnswer" name="otherAnswer"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(":radio").on('click',function (){

if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val()=='other') ) $('#otherAnswer').show(); else $('#otherAnswer').hide();

});
```

Comment: Why not use `this.checked` and `this.value` rather than unnecessarily creating jQuery objects and calling functions?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist its ok. but since I ususally use my jquery objects inside my own code - im automatically doing it... although you right. you can de-jquery the inside object.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more effective.

```
$("input[name='answer']").change(function(){

    if($(this).val() == "yes")
    {
        $("#otherAnswer").show();
    }else{
        $("#otherAnswer").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('input[name=answer]').change(function(){
    if(this.value) == 'yes'{
        $('#otherAnswer').show();
    }else{
        $('#otherAnswer').hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: This won't do what they need; there are three radio buttons with `name="answer"`, two of which should make sure the `input` is hidden.