# jQuery mobile radio events listener

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, radio-button, event-listener

i would like to put a listener when a radio button is checked to add a input text, but i don t really get how work listeners on jquery mobile. (when "radio_choice_v_6c" is checked i want to show "autrenumero")
(i don t really get how to add the listener)
(sry for bad english)

```
<fieldset id="NumTel" data-role="controlgroup" data-theme="a">
      <input name="radio_choice_v_6" id="radio_choice_v_6a" type="radio" checked="checked" value="on">
      <label name="radio_numTel" for="radio_choice-v-6a"></label>
      <input name="radio_choice_v_6" id="radio_choice_v_6b" type="radio" value="off">
      <label name="radio_numMob" for="radio_choice_v_6b"></label> 
      <input name="radio_choice_v_6" id="radio_choice_v_6c" type="radio" value="off">
      <label for="radio_choice_v_6c">Appelez-moi sur ce numéro :</label>
</fieldset>

<div id="labelAutreNumero">
  <input name="autrenumero" id="autrenumero" type="number" value="" placeholder="Numéro" data-mini="true" data-clear-btn="true">
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: I don't think this is related to mobile. Did you try something yet that you can show us ?

Comment: sry but i didn t get what u wanted me to show. i read the jquery-mobile doc but i didn t understand it, i saw some various example but no one functionned. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569796/if-radio-button-is-check-display-a-textbox-jquery http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.2/docs/forms/radiobuttons/events.html)

Comment: Well, you need help on javascript but don't show any javascript code that you tried. There's no problem coming here with a code that doesn't work, if it worked you wouldn't need us, but you at least need to show some efforts, meaning some code, so that we can point the errors in your implementation. And as far as I know this has nothing to do with jQuery mobile, the answer will most probably be standard jQuery

Comment: i tried this
$(":radio").bind ( "change", function(event, ui) {
  alert("change");
});


$(document.getElementById('radio_choice_v_6c')).bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
  alert("change");
});

$("input[type='radio']").bind( "change", function(event, ui) {
  alert("change");
});

(i don t get the syntax of the "input[type='radio]") because it focus all radio and i want only one)

Comment: the first line should work although you should rather look for the `on()` method if you're using recent versions of jQuery. Second line is bad because you mix jQuery and vanilla JS. To select an element by id with jQuery, just do `$('#radio_choice_v_6c')`

Comment: i put functions in $(document).ready(function () {}); but i don t have the alert message i tried this too
with the on()  $('#radio_choice_v_6c').on('change', function( event ){    

        alert('change');  
    });
but doesn t work too
$('#radio_choice_v_6c').click(function () { }); just to see but doesn t work too does it possible it s because the html is generate by js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each radio button a unique value:

```
<fieldset id="NumTel" data-role="controlgroup">
    <input type="radio" name="radio_choice_v_6" id="radio-choice-v-6a" value="on" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radio-choice-v-6a">Choice One</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_choice_v_6" id="radio-choice-v-6b" value="off" />
    <label for="radio-choice-v-6b">Choice Two</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_choice_v_6" id="radio-choice-v-6c" value="numero" />
    <label for="radio-choice-v-6c">Appelez-moi sur ce numéro :</label>
</fieldset>
<div id="labelAutreNumero">
    <input name="autrenumero" id="autrenumero" type="number" value="" placeholder="Numéro" data-mini="true" data-clear-btn="true" />
</div>
```

Then bind the change event within the jQM pagecreate:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $("#labelAutreNumero").hide();

    $("input[name='radio_choice_v_6']").on("change", function() {
        if ($("input[name='radio_choice_v_6']:checked").val() == 'numero')
            $("#labelAutreNumero").show();
        else
            $("#labelAutreNumero").hide();
    });
});
```

In the script, we wait until page1 is created by jQM so that the DOM is ready. Then we hide the number input waiting for the third radio to be checked. Next we handle the change event on all radio buttons with a name of radio_choice_v_6. In here we get the radio that is checked and read its value, then show or hide the input based on the value.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/bgyY2/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for your time, it's work i just used pageshow instead of pagecreate beacause when i used return function to move on a page and comeback to this page the listener wasn t here